# Real Snow addon crashing blender

Tags: add-on, performance

im trying to apply snow to an object in my scene and every single time it crashes. i have a pretty good pc and i know for a fact that specs arent the problem because it worked just find in a fresh blend file. i also made a copy and deleted everything but the object and it still diddnt work. i have tried it on 3 different computers and they all crashed

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UYGkFygBOw-6Z13G-EGhpMAmbeEr94M9/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Putting everything in a new collection and appending it to a new blend file worked